# Why do we use default along with not null in database columns?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Isn't it extra overhead?
When we mention default x (for example, `alter table users add column id default 0` it is not gonna allow null at database level ) . So why use `not null` along with `default` in queries for a column?

Answer (score 4):

A default clause is only applied when you don't reference the column when inserting, explicitly inserting (or updating) `null` to a column will still allow you to store `null`. Using a `not null` constraint prevents that.

So both clauses serve different purposes, and there is no overlap.

The SQL standard allows you to use `DEFAULT` instead of a value to explicitly assign the default value in an insert or update. Be aware though that not all DBMSes support this.

Answer (score 0):

A `DEFAULT` value is useful when you don't want to always specify a value (especially when you have tables with 10+ columns, and a successful `INSERT` only requires a couple column's worth of data).  If you had a `cars` table with a `has_steering_wheel` column (which is `t` in most cases), you could rely on the `DEFAULT` instead of specifying the column every time you wanted to do an `INSERT`.  Basically, it saves you some keystrokes.

A `NOT NULL` constraint is useful when you need to require a value, and there should be no exceptions.  A typical example would be a `color` on a `cars` table.

To combine both `DEFAULT` and `NOT NULL` would be to require a value, and that value doesn't **usually** deviate from the standard.  An example would be a `has_power_locks` column on a `cars` table (typically the answer is `t`, and sometimes it could be `f`, but it should never be `NULL` -- unless your application is coded to handle `NULL` with either `t` or `f`).